# Best method of calculating a grand total of a value for an attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the added total of an attribute value. The value is either a monetary sum eg. `$29.99`, or a text string, eg. `sold`.

I'm using the following code, which I'm sure is not proper. I get a returned value of `NaN`, which I know means "not a number". I have a feeling I may not be properly removing the text string, dollar sign, commas, or all three.

Any help in providing a proper solution is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var total = parseFloat($('span.buyoffer').attr('data-price').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""));
```

Comment: What is the value in `data-price`? Also, rather than use `attr()` to get a data attribute, use `data()`, for example `.data('price')`

Comment: Also, your code should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5s5GA/. You just need to put an `if` condition around the code so that it does not try to `parseInt()` 'sold'

Comment: `parseFloat('')` is `NaN`, so perhaps the resulting string is empty?

Comment: The value in data-price either contains a monentary sum eg. $29.99 or a text string eg. sold. Do I need to be certain I'm properly removing the text and dollar signs from the value prior to calculating? I'm not sure how that affects parseFloat if the values come back with text or dollar signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var total;
$.each($('span.buyoffer'), function(i,v) {
    var val = $(v).attr('data-price');
    if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
        total = total + val
    }
});
//here you will have the total value
```

Comment: `$.isNumeric('$1.23')` returns `false`

Comment: Thanks Parv! The code you originally posted worked perfectly. The edited code you posted did'nt work for me. I listed your original code that worked for me below. One problem, I get a returned value of  143.57999999999996. How can that be fixed? Thanks again!! And thanks to all that offered such quick advice.  `var total = 0;
$("span.buy-offer").each(function() {
  var price = +($(this).attr("data-price").replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""));
  total += price;
});`

Comment: to round the number you can do a to fixed like total = total.toFixed(2). have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Thanks again Parv. I included my code for rounding, which worked for me and used for placement in the web page I'm modifying using greasemonkey.                     `$('<div>Price: $'+ total.toFixed(2) +'</div>').appendTo('.lib-panel .lib-block');` //this is the code used to round the value and place my value in my desired section of a web page

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat('')` returns NaN - you must convert the empty string to a number first. The easiest way is to subtract `0` from it:

```
var total = parseFloat(($('span.buyoffer').attr('data-price').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "")) - 0);
```

Also @Rory McCrossan is correct, using `.data()` is preferred, so:

```
var total = parseFloat(($('span.buyoffer').data('price').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "")) - 0);
```

However, this will still only work if you only have a single `<span class="buyoffer">` element. To calculate the total of all matched elements, you would need to iterate over each one:

```
var total = 0;
$('span.buyoffer').each(function(index, element) {
    total += $(element).data('price').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "") - 0;
});
```

Comment: im sry, but i dont know how you are supposed to get total sum of many values by doing this. .attr will get only the value from the first element from the selected elements

Comment: I made the assumption that the asker already knew how to iterate over multiple matches, since the question was clear that there's only an issue in converting the string 'sold' to a number. Edited to add a more complete example anyway

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/p324u/

```
var sum = 0;
$("span.buyoffer").each(function() {
  var price = +($(this).attr("data-price").replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""));
  sum += price;
});
```